# Wordpress author role vulnerabilities

Tags: wordpress, security

Is it possible for wordpress author role to inject malicious code through their posting? If it possible, how to prevent or minimize those risk if allowing that role is a must?

Thanks for your insight,, appreciated,,,

Answer (score 0):

It´s kind of possible.

While authors can´t post or execute PHP code directly from the editor (its input gets sanitized), they could link to or include malicious (JavaScript) code there, which might be able to penetrate the system.

But I think the risk is relatively low, if you are not using plugins which allow code execution in the editor.

Comment: hi flomei,,.. ohh, by default, wordpress do not allow code execution through editor.. thanks for your insight